# how to call an event of button onclicklistner from one activity class to another activity class

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick

I am working on a project in which the developer has already created a class for the main activity called "**public class ManualTest extends Activity** " and on the same activity there are a few buttons and the developer has implemented on click listener in the following way.

**class starttestclicker implements Button.OnClickListener** and there is some code written on this,

```
    public SMSTestManual mansmstest = null;
    public NetTestManual mannettest = null;
    public ParamInfoTestManual manparaminfotest = null;
    public EmailTestManual manemailtest = null;
    public void onClick(View v)
    { 
               //some code which is responsible to perform some task//
            }
```

I want to perform the same action which this code is performing without clicking any button in a different activity.

I have tried to use callOnClick() method on my another activity(class) but that is not working. Please guide me on how this can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a  class `CommonFunctions` like this, and keep common functions there.

```
public class CommonFunctions {

    public void function1 (String param1, Context cxt1){
        //Perform actions
    }

}
```

Now create its object `commonFunObj` in both activities, and call the function like

```
commonFunObj.function1("param1 txt", getApplicationContext());
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this is for textview clickevent, change it for button click event.

```
public static void onClickSearch(TextView textview, Context context) {
    if (textview != null) {
        String query = textview.getText().toString();
        query = query.replace("(m)", "").replace("(f)", "").replace("(n)", "");
        final Search obj = new Search();
        obj.set_text_to_searchview(query);

        if(InternetConnection.isInternetOn(context)){               
            SearchData_DTO.setSearchData_DTO(new SearchData().getSearched(query, context));
        }
        else{
            SearchData_DTO.setSearchData_DTO(new SearchDataDB().getSearchedDB(query, context));
        }
    }
}
```

and call like this

```
TabFragment1.onClickSearch(tvSynm, getActivity());
```

Comment: But the only problem is that class which  implements the on click listener  is not public